# Vue.js Use data defined in scoped slot within <script> tag

Tags: vue.js

I would like to ask if its possible to reuse data from scoped slot inside script tag.

I have two components
Component A

```
<slot :data="data">
```

Component B

```
<template v-slot="{ data }">
```

Using data within template works, however I would need to use data within  is it possible to use something like this.data inside  ? If I use this.data it is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is **very dirty**!

In Template:

```html
<template v-slot:default="{ data }">
  <div hidden>{{ getScopeData(data) }}</div>
  
  ... bla bla bla ...

</template>
```

In Script:

```js
data() {
  return {
    buffer: {},
  };
},

methods: {
  getScopeData(val) {
    this.$set(this.buffer, 'yourCustomName', val);
    // or
    // I'm not sure what will be reactive
    // this.$set(this.$data, 'buffer', val);
  },
}
```